# How to manually recreate the bootstrap client certificate for OpenShift 3.11 master?

Tags: openshift, okd

Our origin-node.service on the master node fails with:

```
root@master> systemctl start origin-node.service
Job for origin-node.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status origin-node.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

root@master> systemctl status origin-node.service -l

[...]
May 05 07:17:47 master origin-node[44066]: bootstrap.go:195] Part of the existing bootstrap client certificate is expired: 2020-02-20 13:14:27 +0000 UTC
May 05 07:17:47 master origin-node[44066]: bootstrap.go:56] Using bootstrap kubeconfig to generate TLS client cert, key and kubeconfig file
May 05 07:17:47 master origin-node[44066]: certificate_store.go:131] Loading cert/key pair from "/etc/origin/node/certificates/kubelet-client-current.pem".
May 05 07:17:47 master origin-node[44066]: server.go:262] failed to run Kubelet: cannot create certificate signing request: Post https://lb.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com:8443/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/certificatesigningrequests: EOF
```

So it seems that kubelet-client-current.pem and/or kubelet-server-current.pem contains an expired certificate and the service tries to create a CSR using an endpoint which is probably not yet available (because the master is down). We tried redeploying the certificates according to the OpenShift documentation [Redeploying Certificates](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/redeploying_certificates.html), but this fails while detecting an expired certificate:

```
root@master> ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts  openshift-master/redeploy-openshift-ca.yml

[...]
TASK [openshift_certificate_expiry : Fail when certs are near or already expired] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Cluster certificates found to be expired or within 60 days of expiring. You may view the report at /root/cert-expiry-report.20200505T042754.html or /root/cert-expiry-report.20200505T042754.json.\n"}
[...]



root@master> cat /root/cert-expiry-report.20200505T042754.json

[...]
      "kubeconfigs": [
        {
          "cert_cn": "O:system:cluster-admins, CN:system:admin",
          "days_remaining": -75,
          "expiry": "2020-02-20 13:14:27",
          "health": "expired",
          "issuer": "CN=openshift-signer@1519045219 ",
          "path": "/etc/origin/node/node.kubeconfig",
          "serial": 27,
          "serial_hex": "0x1b"
        },
        {
          "cert_cn": "O:system:cluster-admins, CN:system:admin",
          "days_remaining": -75,
          "expiry": "2020-02-20 13:14:27",
          "health": "expired",
          "issuer": "CN=openshift-signer@1519045219 ",
          "path": "/etc/origin/node/node.kubeconfig",
          "serial": 27,
          "serial_hex": "0x1b"
        },
[...]

  "summary": {
    "expired": 2,
    "ok": 22,
    "total": 24,
    "warning": 0
  }
}
```

There is a guide for OpenShift 4.4 for [Recovering from expired control plane certificates](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/backup_and_restore/disaster_recovery/scenario-3-expired-certs.html), but that does not apply for 3.11 and we did not find such a guide for our version.

Is it possible to recreate the expired certificates without a running master node for 3.11? Thanks for any help.

OpenShift Ansible: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/releases/tag/openshift-ansible-3.11.153-2

*Update 2020-05-06:* I also executed redeploy-certificates.yml, but it fails at the same TASK:

```
root@master> ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts playbooks/redeploy-certificates.yml

[...]

TASK [openshift_certificate_expiry : Fail when certs are near or already expired] ******************************************************************************
Wednesday 06 May 2020  04:07:06 -0400 (0:00:00.909)       0:01:07.582 ********* 
fatal: [master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Cluster certificates found to be expired or within 60 days of expiring. You may view the report at /root/cert-expiry-report.20200506T040603.html or /root/cert-expiry-report.20200506T040603.json.\n"}
```

*Update 2020-05-11:* Running with `-e openshift_certificate_expiry_fail_on_warn=False` results in:

```
root@master> ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts -e openshift_certificate_expiry_fail_on_warn=False playbooks/redeploy-certificates.yml

[...]

TASK [Wait for master API to come back online] *****************************************************************************************************************
Monday 11 May 2020  03:48:56 -0400 (0:00:00.111)       0:02:25.186 ************ 
skipping: [master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com]

TASK [openshift_control_plane : restart master] ****************************************************************************************************************
Monday 11 May 2020  03:48:56 -0400 (0:00:00.257)       0:02:25.444 ************ 
changed: [master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com] => (item=api)
changed: [master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com] => (item=controllers)

RUNNING HANDLER [openshift_control_plane : verify API server] **************************************************************************************************
Monday 11 May 2020  03:48:57 -0400 (0:00:00.945)       0:02:26.389 ************ 
FAILED - RETRYING: verify API server (120 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: verify API server (119 retries left).
[...]
FAILED - RETRYING: verify API server (1 retries left).
fatal: [master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 120, "changed": false, "cmd": ["curl", "--silent", "--tlsv1.2", "--max-time", "2", "--cacert", "/etc/origin/master/ca-bundle.crt", "https://lb.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com:8443/healthz/ready"], "delta": "0:00:00.182367", "end": "2020-05-11 03:51:52.245644", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 35, "start": "2020-05-11 03:51:52.063277", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}



root@master> systemctl status origin-node.service -l

[...]


May 11 04:23:28 master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com origin-node[109972]: E0511 04:23:28.077964  109972 bootstrap.go:195] Part of the existing bootstrap client certificate is expired: 2020-02-20 13:14:27 +0000 UTC
May 11 04:23:28 master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com origin-node[109972]: I0511 04:23:28.078001  109972 bootstrap.go:56] Using bootstrap kubeconfig to generate TLS client cert, key and kubeconfig file
May 11 04:23:28 master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com origin-node[109972]: I0511 04:23:28.080555  109972 certificate_store.go:131] Loading cert/key pair from "/etc/origin/node/certificates/kubelet-client-current.pem".
May 11 04:23:28 master.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com origin-node[109972]: F0511 04:23:28.130968  109972 server.go:262] failed to run Kubelet: cannot create certificate signing request: Post https://lb.openshift-cluster.mydomain.com:8443/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/certificatesigningrequests: EOF

[...]
```

Comment: From your output it seems you tried the `redeploy-openshift-ca` playbook, but have you also tried to use the `redeploy-certificates.yml` playbook?

Comment: Yes I did, but it fails at the same task `TASK [openshift_certificate_expiry : Fail when certs are near or already expired`.

Answer (score 1):

The `openshift_certificate_expiry` role uses the `openshift_certificate_expiry_fail_on_warn` variable to determine if the playbook should fail when the days left are less than `openshift_certificate_expiry_warning_days`.

So try running the `redeploy-certificates.yml` with this additional variable set to "False":

```
ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts -e openshift_certificate_expiry_fail_on_warn=False playbooks/redeploy-certificates.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately this does not succeed either. I have updated the question above with the result. In the service status you can see that the corresponding certificates were still not updated: `bootstrap.go:195] Part of the existing bootstrap client certificate is expired: 2020-02-20 13:14:27 +0000 UTC`

Comment: Thank you for the update, seems your cluster is in a really bad state. Does the same happen when you also add `-e openshift_redeploy_openshift_ca=true`? If that one fails as well, it might be worth (after backing them up!) to delete all existing certificates / keys and to try to completely redeploy all certificates and keys. At this point I do not think we have anything to loose. But as noted, make sure to back up the certificates and keys before deleting anything.

Comment: We tried to completely redeploy the certificates, but this failed too, so we ended up reinstalling OpenShift. It still seems weird that there is no easy solution for this. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: It worked for me. Running redeploy-certificates.yml even without setting openshift_certificate_expiry_fail_on_warn=False has solved issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same case in customer environment, this error is because the certified was expiry, i "cheated" changing da S.O date before the expiry date. And the origin-node service started in my masters:

```
 systemctl status origin-node
● origin-node.service - OpenShift Node
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/origin-node.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sáb 2021-02-20 20:22:21 -02; 6min ago
     Docs: https://github.com/openshift/origin
 Main PID: 37230 (hyperkube)
   Memory: 79.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/origin-node.service
           └─37230 /usr/bin/hyperkube kubelet --v=2 --address=0.0.0.0 --allow-privileged=true --anonymous-auth=true --authentication-token-webhook=true --authentication-token-webhook-cache-ttl=5m --authorization-mode=Webhook --authorization-webhook-c...
Você tem mensagem de correio em /var/spool/mail/okd
```

Comment: Describe how to do and where changes must be applied, for example address of files need to be changed or command need to be executed for making changes...

Comment: To get back in time, first disable the NTP synchronisation, and change the date using `systemctl disable ntpd.service; date -s "2 days ago"`